# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined onClick

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-router

A am creating a login system using aws cognito. In the Navbar.js component i have a Log Out button that i want to redirect after it's clicked. I used the push method for redirect but get the error "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined".

This method worked on all other components except this. All the imports are the same on all components.

Is this happening because the Navbar.js component is not nested inside the Switch component in App.js? Thats the only thing i can think of that may cause the issue...

**Navbar.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Auth } from "aws-amplify";

export default class Navbar extends Component {
  handleLogOut = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    try {
      Auth.signOut();
      this.props.auth.setAuthStatus(false);
      this.props.auth.setUser(null);
      this.props.history.push("/");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <nav className="navbar" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
        <div className="navbar-brand">
          <a className="navbar-item" href="/">
            <img
              src="hexal-logo.png"
              width="112"
              height="28"
              alt="hexal logo"
            />
          </a>
        </div>

        <div id="navbarBasicExample" className="navbar-menu">
          <div className="navbar-start">
            <a href="/" className="navbar-item">
              Home
            </a>
            <a href="/products" className="navbar-item">
              Products
            </a>
            <a href="/admin" className="navbar-item">
              Admin
            </a>
          </div>

          <div className="navbar-end">
            <div className="navbar-item">
              {this.props.auth.isAuthenticated && this.props.auth.user && (
                <p>Hello {this.props.auth.user.username}</p>
              )}
              <div className="buttons">
                {!this.props.auth.isAuthenticated && (
                  <>
                    <a href="/register" className="button is-primary">
                      <strong>Register</strong>
                    </a>
                    <a href="/login" className="button is-light">
                      Log in
                    </a>
                  </>
                )}
                {this.props.auth.isAuthenticated && (
                  <a
                    href="/"
                    onClick={this.handleLogOut}
                    className="button is-light"
                  >
                    Log Out
                  </a>
                )}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Products from "./components/Products";
import ProductAdmin from "./components/ProductAdmin";
import LogIn from "./components/auth/LogIn";
import Register from "./components/auth/Register";
import ForgotPassword from "./components/auth/ForgotPassword";
import ForgotPasswordVerification from "./components/auth/ForgotPasswordVerification";
import ChangePassword from "./components/auth/ChangePassword";
import ChangePasswordConfirm from "./components/auth/ChangePasswordConfirm";
import Welcome from "./components/auth/Welcome";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import { Auth } from "aws-amplify";
import { library } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";
import { faEdit } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
library.add(faEdit);

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    isAuthenticated: false,
    isAuthenticating: true,
    user: null
  };

  setAuthStatus = authenticated => {
    this.setState({ isAuthenticated: authenticated });
  };

  setUser = user => {
    this.setState({ user: user });
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      const session = await Auth.currentSession();
      this.setAuthStatus(true);
      console.log(session);
      const user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
      this.setUser(user);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
    this.setState({ isAuthenticating: false });
  }

  render() {
    const authProps = {
      isAuthenticated: this.state.isAuthenticated,
      user: this.state.user,
      setAuthStatus: this.setAuthStatus,
      setUser: this.setUser
    };
    return (
      !this.state.isAuthenticating && (
        <div className="App">
          <Router>
            <div>
              <Navbar auth={authProps} />
              <Switch>
                <Route
                  exact
                  path="/"
                  render={props => <Home {...props} auth={authProps} />}
                />
                <Route
                  exact
                  path="/products"
                  render={props => <Products {...props} auth={authProps} />}
                />
                <Route
                  exact
                  path="/admin"
                  render={props => <ProductAdmin {...props} auth={authProps} />}
                />
                <Route
                  exact
                  path="/login"
                  render={props => <LogIn {...props} auth={authProps} />}
                />
                <Route
                  exact
                  path="/register"
                  render={props => <Register {...props} auth={authProps} />}
                />
                <Route
                  exact
                  path="/forgotpassword"
                  render={props => (
                    <ForgotPassword {...props} auth={authProps} />
                  )}
                />
                <Route
                  exact
                  path="/forgotpasswordverification"
                  render={props => (
                    <ForgotPasswordVerification {...props} auth={authProps} />
                  )}
                />
                <Route
                  exact
                  path="/changepassword"
                  render={props => (
                    <ChangePassword {...props} auth={authProps} />
                  )}
                />
                <Route
                  exact
                  path="/changepasswordconfirmation"
                  render={props => (
                    <ChangePasswordConfirm {...props} auth={authProps} />
                  )}
                />
                <Route
                  exact
                  path="/welcome"
                  render={props => <Welcome {...props} auth={authProps} />}
                />
              </Switch>
              <Footer />
            </div>
          </Router>
        </div>
      )
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: The problem is that your `Navbar` component is not a `<Route/>` component or anything like that, it's just rendered as a child of the `<Router/>` - which doesn't give it inherent access to the react router's `history` prop. You'll have to manually pass in the `history` prop to it using something like Emanuele's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to attach the component to the router using the `withRouter` HOC:

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

class Navbar extends Component {
  ...
}

export default withRouter(Navbar)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm no React expert but it looks like you're trying to call `this.props.history.push("/");` while `history` is not defined when you're calling the component, only `auth` is defined here:

```
<Navbar auth={authProps} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use withRouter hook as @emanuele mentioned or pass the history prop from your app.js to the component